# How to change pagedlist's links name when using "OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime" in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I'm trying to change name "LinkToFirstPageFormat" or "LinkToPreviousPageFormat" and trying to use "OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime"

Here is my PagedListPager

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.video, page => Url.Action("video_play", new { page = page }), new PagedListRenderOptions { LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<< Next", LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "<", LinkToNextPageFormat = ">", LinkToLastPageFormat = "Last >>" })
```

Allright everthing is fine at this moment but when  I'm trying to use render option's "OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime" property here as you can see at below I get "no overload method PagedlistPager takes 4 argument"

`@Html.PagedListPager(Model.video, page => Url.Action("video_play", new { page = page }), new PagedListRenderOptions { LinkToFirstPageFormat = "<< Next", LinkToPreviousPageFormat = "<", LinkToNextPageFormat = ">", LinkToLastPageFormat = "Last >>" },PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime)`

So how can I change links name with using PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime?

Answer (score 5):

Allright I have found the solution if anyone encounter same problem you can use "MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay=5" property as you can see at below

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.video, page => Url.Action("video_play", new { page = page }), new PagedListRenderOptions { LinkToFirstPageFormat = String.Format("<< Next"), LinkToPreviousPageFormat = String.Format("<"), LinkToNextPageFormat = String.Format(">"), LinkToLastPageFormat = String.Format("Last >>"),MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay=5 })
```